# XCode suggesting @selector with double parenthesis to solve mismatch types

Tags: objective-c, selector, type-mismatch

After activating `-Werror=selector` flag on Xcode, I noticed that I had the following issue:

> "Several methods with selector 'methodName:' of mismatched types are
>   found for the @selector expression"

The thing is, XCode is suggesting that I replace `@selector(methodName:)` with `@selector((methodName:))` in order to fix this.

I can't find anything talking about this, explaining why. Does anyone have an idea?

### Update

So I experimented with `@selector((methodName))`, and I created a three classes.

Two of them, had implementations of `methodName`, but with different returning types. For example:

```
@interface C1
    -(void)methodName;
@end

@interface C2
    -(id)methodName;
@end
```

Then, the third class, had a method were it defines a selector, with double parenthesis, for `methodName` and passes it trough parameters, as a quick example:

```
#import "C1.h"
#import "C2.h"

-(void)selExample {
  SEL selector = @selector((methodName));
  C1 * obj = [[[C1 alloc] init] autorelease];
  [obj performSelector:selector];
}
```

Note: The third class does not have the `methodName` implemented.

Trying to compile this with `-Werror=selector`, XCode gives this error message:

```
No method with selector 'methodName' is implemented in this translation unit
```

So double parenthesis in a `@selector` seems to force the compiler to look for the implementation in the class were it is defined. If I take just use `@selector(methodName)`, it will just throw type mismatch error.

What do you think?

Comment: In statements like `if ((foo=bar))` double parentheses tell the compiler that you know what you are doing and `=` is not a typo. Could be the same with selector expressions - I think double parentheses tell compiler that yes, you are aware that there are several methods with mismatched return types your selector could be referring to, and you intended it.

Comment: I suspect that could be the case, but I would like to know for sure. I haven't seen any example of this online.